# Home screen doesn't use the full screen width

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, home-screen, moto-x

So as of a couple days ago, something is different about my home screen(s). Where once the icons were evenly spread, now they're crammed to the left, leaving a bar of empty space in the right that just shows my wallpaper.

I could deal with this, but I can no longer swipe left from the right edge of the screen to get to my other home screens - it only works if I start the gesture on the part that has icons. How do I get the full width back?

Comment: can you share screenshot of your device? It will be more helpful..

Comment: Sure: http://imgur.com/5J9P292

Comment: Do you use a custom Launcher? For example Nova allows you to specify the grid density allowing precision and placement. This allows for some shortcut concentration like on the left side, or intentional grid clearance like the right-side, in this fashion.

Comment: Nope, vanilla configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is clearing the cache and data for your android launcher. If you go to settings -> application manager and then to all apps, you should eventually find your launcher. I would recommend taking some screenshots of how your home screen is organised before doing this though; this will end up getting rid of your home screen layout.

Comment: I deleted reference to your email for two reasons 1. Answers are expected to be complete without reference to a personal communication. If OP needs, he can always seek clarification by posting a comment below your answer, and you can clarify. 2. Plenty of sites copy the questions from here and your email could lead to people spamming you